# Do questions about specific StackOverflow implementation details belong on SO or Meta?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267737/how-does-stackoverflow-create-its-question-urls) has several discussion comments going back and forth about whether the question belongs on SO or Meta.

The question is asking about how a specific feature of the site is implemented from a coding perspective (so that the OP might duplicate it in their own implementation), which can make it a legitimate programming question.

According to the Meta FAQ: "If your "question is about ... Stack Overflow / The core Stack Exchange engine", it should be asked here.

Here are some similar example questions on Meta:

- [Textarea buttons and preview: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66515/textarea-buttons-and-preview-how-does-it-work)
- [How does Stack Overflow do caching?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/how-does-stack-overflow-do-caching)
- [How does Stack Overflow syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-stack-overflow-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well)
- [How does SO enforce the daily vote limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75232/how-does-so-enforce-the-daily-vote-limits)

**Where do these questions belong?**

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that it belongs on Meta, as it asks a direct question about the SE engine. Though, [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) says that it belongs on SO because it can be used as an example and generic question about the used programming technique (URL rewriting), and he has a point <sub>(and a diamond, don't forget the diamond)</sub>.

I'd reword the question to be more generic and leave it on SO.

About the others, those are more direct questions about SE-specific things, as far as I can see.